# JQuery ajax request data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is a ajax request like this:

```
var user = {
    username: 'levi',
    password: '111111'
};
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    data: {user: user},
    success: function(data) {}
 });
```

the url is `?user%5Busername%5D=levi1&user%5Bpassword%5D=11111"`

but what I need is `?user.username=levi1&user.password=11111"`

Comment: you should use POST for these data , if u wish to put in production

Answer (score 0):

The url itself replaces special characters.

Read through the link http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Also you may encode the url using encodeURIComponent();

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax to allow for dots in the object's keys:

```
var user = {'user.username': 'levi', 'user.password': '111111'};
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    data: user,
    success: function(data) {}
 });
```

Comment: Or just data={ "user.username":"....","user.password":"...."}; and data:data, later

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 It's just what I thought of first? Obviously there are other ways that are just as valid.

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice - Your's indeed valid, but it is considered a very bad practice due to the fact that [it is very slow](http://jsperf.com/different-object-creating-procedure) and consumes more character spaces.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Not to be nitpicky, but because we can't define the object like {user.username: 'levi'} and have to use {'user.username': 'levi'}, those benchmarks don't necessarily apply.

Comment: Actually, I just did some benchmarking myself and found that {'user.username': 'levi'} is about twice as fast as using array-style assignment on Chrome, while the speeds are about equal on Firefox. So performance is still a bit better but not as much as if we could create the object without using string-keys at all, like {username: 'levi'}

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice - It is slower is because I think if you do `obj["key"]`, the browser will have to copy the whole object just to create one more key-pair, while `{obj: key}` the browser already knows the length and it does not need to copy the whole object.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Might be. Not sure why {'user.username': 'levi'} is slower than {username: 'levi'} though.

Comment: I tested it but I don't see a big difference in them though. (Actually [`{"key": "value"}` is faster in my test](http://jsperf.com/string-as-key).)